# Find image type in python openCV

Tags: python, opencv

I recently had some issues finding the type of a template image i'm using for pattern matching purposes. I use the python version of OpenCV, and the image returned by `imread` does not seem to have a "type" property like in the C++ OpenCV implementation.

I would like to access the type of the template to create a "dst" `Mat` having the same size and type of the template.

Here is the code :

```
template = cv2.imread('path-to-file', 1)
height, width = template.shape[:-1]
dst = cv2.cv.CreateMat(width,height, template.type) 
--->'Error :numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'type'
```

Do you have any thoughts about this issue ?

Thanks a lot for your answers.

Comment: Since images are numpy arrays, the type is given by the `dtype` attribute.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

While it's true that the numpy array type can be accessed using `template.dtype`, that's not the type you want to pass to `cv2.cv.CreateMat()` , e.g.

```
In [41]: cv2.imread('abalone.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_COLOR).dtype         
Out[41]: dtype('uint8')

In [42]: cv2.imread('abalone.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE).dtype
Out[42]: dtype('uint8')
```

If you pass the numpy array's `dtype` to `cv2.cv.CreateMat()` you will get this error, e.g.

```
cv2.cv.CreateMat(500, 500, template.dtype)
```

> TypeError: an integer is required

And as you can see, the dtype doesn't change for grayscale/color, however

```
In [43]: cv2.imread('abalone.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE).shape
Out[43]: (250, 250)

In [44]: cv2.imread('abalone.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_COLOR).shape
Out[44]: (250, 250, 3)
```

Here you can see that it's the `img.shape` that is more useful to you.

### Create a numpy matrix from the template

So you want to create a object from your template you can do :

```
import numpy as np
dst = np.zeros(template.shape, dtype=template.dtype)
```

That should be useable as far as Python API goes.

### cv2.cv.CreateMat

If you want this using the C++ way of creating matrices, you should remember the type with which you opened your template:

```
template = cv2.imread('path-to-file', 1) # 1 means cv2.IMREAD_COLOR 
height, width = template.shape[:-1]    
dst = cv2.cv.CreateMat(height, width, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
```

**If you insist on guessing the type:**
While it's not perfect, you can guess by reading the length of the dimensions of the matrix, an image of type `IMREAD_COLOR` has 3 dimensions, while `IMREAD_GRAYSCALE` has 2

```
In [58]: len(cv2.imread('abalone.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_COLOR).shape)
Out[58]: 3

In [59]: len(cv2.imread('abalone.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE).shape)
Out[59]: 2
```